# TextArea htmlText does not update text property when set (Flex)

Tags: apache-flex, textarea, htmltext

If setting the htmlText property on an mx TextArea the text property stays 'null' until the TextArea is manually edited. Is there a way of updating the text property as soon as the htmlText property is set?

e.g.

textArea.htmlText = str;
trace(textArea.text)

result = null

Many thanks,
Adam

Comment: does it happen a few seconds after the `htmlText` is set, like for example when the html is actually rendered? If it does, you can get it by using timeouts

Comment: Yes you're right, thank you. However isn't there a way of listening for when the text property updates. The 'change' event of the TextArea is only triggered by user change. The documentation mentions that a 'textChanged' event should be fired when the text property is updated however I can find no such event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `validateNow()` on the `textArea` after setting the `htmlText` property you can force the text property to be updated instantly.

e.g.

```
textArea.htmlText = str;
textArea.validateNow();
trace(textArea.text);

result = HtmlToText( str );
```